# Что за член предложения?

Tags: синтаксис

В предложении "Мы молодой весны гонцы" "мы" - подлежащее, "гонцы" - сказуемое (составное именное), а "молодой весны" - какой член предложения? (Что-то я запуталась совсем...)

Comment: Гонцы (чьи?) весны; весны (какой?) молодой. К каким членам предложения ставятся такие вопросы?

Comment: Я думаю, что это определения.

Comment: А не относится все это сочетание - "молодой весны гонцы" - к именной части  сказуемого? Я  понимаю, что на эти вопросы отвечают определения. Но смущает составное именное сказуемое.

Answer (score 2):

*Мы молодой весны гонцы.*

Мы (есть кто?) гонцы - сост.именное сказуемое.

Гонцы (чьи?) весны - несогласованное определение.

Весны (какой?) молодой - согласованное определение.

Словосочетание ***молодой весны гонцы*** не является слитным (фразеологизированным). Это свободное сложное словосочетание, которое легко делится на два простых: гонцы весны и молодой весны.

Сложные словосочетания представляют собою распространение слова целым словосочетанием.

Составное именное сказуемое **гонцы** распространено целым словосочетанием **молодой весны**, поэтому все три слова воспринимаются как что-то одно по смыслу, но **это одно** - *сложное словосочетание*, *которое синтаксически легко расчленяется на два.* Каждый компонент выполняет свою синтаксическую роль.

Comment: Можно прояснить один момент, на примере 3 предложений: 1. Мы гонцы отца. 2. Мы отцовы гонцы. 3. Мы отцовские гонцы.
В 3. Вопрос: гонцы какие - отцовские, определение выраженное прилагательным?
В 2. Вопрос: гонцы чьи - отцовы, определение выраженное кратким прилагательным?
В 1. Почему не вопрос: гонцы кого -отца, определение выраженное существительным. Почему вместо этого спрашивают снова чьи? хотя чьи уже было во втором, для кратких прилагательных.

Comment: Благодарю за точный ответ! Всё, как я и думала (но - сомневалась...)